# Make textboxes, Checkboxes, Dropdowns in DetailsView 508 compliant

Tags: detailsview, section508

I have detailsview which has few dropdownlist and Checkboxes. Now I am trying to make these input fields 508 compliant.

Does anyone know about this fix?

Answer (score 3):

The [applicable paragraph of Section 508](http://www.section508.gov/index.cfm?fuseAction=stdsdoc#Web)  is

> (n) When electronic forms are designed to be completed on-line, the form shall allow people using assistive technology to access the information, field elements, and functionality required for completion and submission of the form, including all directions and cues.

This corresponds to the [section of WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WAI-WEBCONTENT-19990505/#gl-complex-elements) on "context and orientation information." Proper use of the `label` element, including the `for` label, covers almost everything related to dropdown lists and checkboxes. For example:

```
<label for="mysel">Select a language:</label>
    <select name="mysel" id="mysel">
        <option value="en-us">US English</option>
```

etc., or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycb" id="mycb" value="Reminders - Yes"/> 
<label for="mycb">I would like to receive email reminders</label>
```

Comment: Here's the new link:http://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-section-508-standards/section-508-standards#22

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.
fully accessible and meet the 508 criteria as well. textbox, checkbox, and dropdown works on screen readers and keyboard access

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Accessible DetailsView</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="textbox1">Textbox 1:</label>
      <input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" aria-describedby="textbox1-desc">
      <div id="textbox1-desc" class="sr-only">Enter text in Textbox 1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="checkbox1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1">
        Checkbox 1
      </label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="dropdown1">Dropdown 1:</label>
      <select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" aria-describedby="dropdown1-desc">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <div id="dropdown1-desc" class="sr-only">Select an option from Dropdown 1</div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<style>
  .sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
  }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).